# How to move applications to external memory card on ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, external-sd, app2sd

I have an android ICS tablet and I'd like to install applications on the **external memory card** (not the internal memory / internal SD).

Is it possible to do so? A solution that does not require rooting would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The "official" version disappeared in ICS. But you can use root-solutions (creating symbolic links) Therefore you need two partitions on your sdCard.

A complete explanation can be found here: 
http://www.modaco.com/topic/331205-guide-how-to-get-more-free-space-for-your-apps/

(The root-variants still work)

you will need a rooted phone though

Comment: Which version are you mentioning?

Comment: You can use any of those versions, which require partitioning your SD-Card. But as I wrote: You have to root your device, sorry. 
If its about memory. Most Applications which use a big amount of disc space can have their data saved on SD. (Like Navigation applications). If it is a specific application try searching for a solution for that specific application. For example: Sygic can save its maps on SD